# Evaluate middle part of the 'for loop' in java before checking

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int i=0; i < string.length() || i < 5 ; i++) {
    // some code
}
```

Is it possible to evaluate the middle part based on whichever expression is smaller?

Comment: So you want to change the or to an and?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can phrase your loop as this:

```
for (int i=0; i < Math.min(string.length(), 5); i++) {
    // some code
}
```

Here we are taking the smaller of 5 or the string length as the upper bound of the loop, and the code is clear to someone else who might have to read it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the loop to terminate when `i` reaches the smaller of the two expressions, use AND:

```
for(int i=0; i < string.length() && i < 5 ;i++)
```